# Do I need to use paint or just cleaning agent for marks on kitchen wall?

Tags: drywall, walls, kitchens, cleaning

I have some marks on the kitchen wall from a tall trash can. Do I need to paint over them? If so, do I need to degloss/sand the wall first?

I have tried a damp towel and failed. Can they be cleaned off with some cleaning products?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Many paints "chalk", allowing surface dirt to be scrubbed off gently (e.g. with a weak solution of laundry detergent), but this also removes a very thin layer of paint. If cleaning changes the appearance noticeably, then repainting could be done.

Depending on the type of paint, no pretreatment *might* be necessary. Flat latex paint can often be reapplied after washing (to remove any surface dirt, e.g. evaporated cooking oil). Other paints are less forgiving, and might require sanding. See [PaintInfo.com](http://www.paintinfo.com/cn/cnp-018.shtml), [This Old House](https://www.thisoldhouse.com/discussions/topic/help-painting-over-semi-gloss), etc.

Comment: Thanks! The problem is I have no idea what kind of paint is on there. I am considering doing a paint match with a chip from the wall if it turns out repainting is in order.

Answer (score 1):

Try starting using different solutions on your damp cloth. Using baking soda with a damp towel has been known to work as well as a fresh pencil eraser. If that doesn't do it, then try a dry-cleaning solvent or a spot remover. Repainting would be the logical next step if any of these options do not work or if they damage the paint on the wall.

Comment: My suggestion is mr clean magic eraser for that type of marking.